# How to fix counting the occurrence in a substring in java

Tags: java

I am trying to get the number of *Male* and *Female* using **substring**. but in this case I have made 2 classes and use a scanner to input how many records I want. How do I combine the the number of counts in a **for loop**? I have got the count of the **M** and **F**'s but it did not get my expected output. I have tried to remove the for loop and just only the `A[i] = Output` but it needs to be in a loop or else it may be error. If I put again the for loop it works but it was seperated "it's on the Output box".
If I am doing wrong plz let me know.

```
public class Input {

    String info, gender;
    int resultf;
    int resultm;

    static Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    public void inputted() {

        System.out.print("Enter a Gender: ");
        info = in.nextLine();

        gender = info.substring(0,1);
        }

    public void Output() {
        resultm = info.length() - info.replaceAll("M", "").length();
        resultf = info.length() - info.replaceAll("F", "").length();
        System.out.println("Male: "+resultm);
        System.out.println("Female: "+resultf);
        }

}
```

```
public class Output {

    static Input A[] = new Input [100];
    static Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void main (String args []) {

        int i, size;
        //Input
        System.out.print("Enter how many record: ");
        size = in.nextInt();

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            A[i] = new Input();
            A[i].inputted();
        }   

        System.out.println();
        //Print
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.println("Gender: "+A[i].gender);
        }

        System.out.println();
        //Output Section
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            A[i].Output();
        }
    }

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter how many record: 2
Enter a Gender: M
Enter a Gender: F

Gender: M
Gender: F

Male: 1
Female: 0
Male: 0
Female: 1
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
Enter how many record: 2
Enter a Gender: M
Enter a Gender: F

Gender: M
Gender: F

Male: 1
Female: 1
```

Comment: Each instance of `Input` that you create will have its own copy of `resultf` and `resultm`. You can get your desired output by simply using one `Input` object and updating it over and over in your loop rather than using an `Input[]`. I would also recommend you only use the `Scanner` methods in the `Output` class and instead just increment the variables in `Input` by accessing the variable directly or with additional methods.

Comment: I also recommend you don't call `nextInt()` followed by calls to `nextLine()` because that can lead to [problems with skipping input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to count it in main function, not in class Input.

```java
public class Input {
  //add functions below
  public boolean IsMale(){return resultm == 1;}
  public boolean IsFemale(){return resultf == 1;}

  //another way without boolean
  public int GetMaleCount(){return resultm;}
  public int GetFemaleCount(){return resultf;}
}
```

Change the Output Section in main to below:

```
int male = 0;
int female = 0;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  //if(A[i].IsMale()){male ++;}
  //if(A[i].IsFemale()){female ++;}
  //another way without boolean
  male += A[i].GetMaleCount();
  female += A[i].GetFemaleCount();
}
System.out.println("Male: "+male);
System.out.println("Female: "+female);
```

Comment: From OPs logic `resultm` and `resultf` can never be `1` if user inputs more than one character for gender. Hence your `IsMale()` and `IsFemale()` method would always return false for similar senario.

Comment: Is there other way to do this without using Boolean? This code works. But I haven't used Boolean before so I don't know how to simulate this in my mind.

Comment: @Miao I just update the answer that without using `boolean`.

Comment: Thanks! Anyways, can i ask why ```resultm == 1``` and ```resultm == 1``` is needed to be returned if i'm using the boolean?

Comment: When you want to know the total count of gender, can't do that in each `Input` object `A[i]`, in main function, you can get all object's gender count, then just different method to count. First is to check object has male or female or none, `resultm == 1` is doing this, the second way is to return `resultm` value, add it in main function.

Answer (score 0):

In your last loop in `main` you called the `Input.Output` base on the size of your array, and you print both of the gender on that method. Change your `Input.Output` on how you print the data.
Try adding checking `if` to check if your printing male or female. Or just change the logic for printing the result.